# Get XML with single Data

Tags: c#, xml

This site http://geoiptool.com/data.php report data in XML

```
<markers> 
    <marker lat="xxx" lng="xxx" city="xxx" 
        country="xxx" host="xxx" ip="xx" code="xx"/> 
</markers>
```

is it possible get the lat, lng, city and country? I tried this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("http://geoiptool.com/data.php");
string xmlcontents = doc.InnerXml;
```

but return all xml data

Comment: try doc.Load("http://geoiptool.com/data.php").Descendants("marker")
                    .Attributes("lat")

Comment: not work this code =(

Comment: @TamilSelvan, `doc.Load` returns void. You would need to break your code into 2 statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you get the node you are looking for (marker), you can grab the attributes from it. Note that it is usually a good idea to check if the attribute is null before accessing a property from it. This is an example of getting the lat attribute:

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load("http://geoiptool.com/data.php");

    var marker = doc.SelectSingleNode("//markers/marker");
    string lat = marker.Attributes["lat"].Value;
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option (instead of `XmlDocument`) is to use `XElement`. This allows the use of Linq, which makes everything better.

```
XElement root = XElement.Load("http://geoiptool.com/data.php"); //check me on that, not sure if it will handle urls
foreach(var marker in root.Elements("marker"))
{
    string lat = marker.Attribute("lat").Value;
    string lng = marker.Attribute("lng").Value;
    ...
}
```